# Print file to specific printer in powershell?

Tags: powershell

So Im creating a file and sending to print to a printer called UNBILLING, but for some weird reason the command will use the default printer instead of the one mentioned. Why?

Here is the code I use

```
 start-process -filepath "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\$archivo" -verb print | out-printer "UNBILLING"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified the printer you are printing to exists? Hint: Use `Get-Printer -Name *` to get a list of all the printers you have. For network printers, you might have to define \\server\printer as [per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-printer?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Using '-verb print' on the start-process command is equavilant to right-clicking the document and selecting print.  This will always attempt to use the default printer.  At that point, there is nothing to pass to the out-printer command as you have already printed to the default printer.

Answer (score 0):

This will send the content of the file to the printer and make sure that the printer is actually installed.

```
Get-Content -Path "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\$archivo" | Out-Printer -Name (Get-Printer | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "UNBILLING"}.Name
```